# What is the most efficient way to determine if a path exists between 2 nodes?

Tags: c, depth-first-search

I'm given an array of integers in C (meant to represent a 2D matrix of nodes) which can hold either 0s or 1s. Given the coordinates of 2 '0' nodes, I am supposed to simply find out whether or not a path of 0s exists between them (where nodes connect adjacently -- up, down, left, right).

Is there a simpler alternative to BFS/DFS I can use to solve my problem? I know that with BFS/DFS, I can not only determine the existence of a path, but also find and return a working path? Just wondering if that's overkill for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in the general case depth first search (with a cache to make sure you only visit a given node once) is usually the fastest way to check if a path exists.

If your data is clustered then finding a connection between clusters first may be faster.  If you need to do this check many times, then building these clusters once and searching on them can help a lot.

There are possibly optimizations you can make if you know more information about your graph.  For example, if you know any connected nodes must also be neighbours then you would use BFS instead of DFS.  If your graph has some kind of spatial (or similar) relationship, then A* is likely faster then DFS.

Without knowing more about your specific case I can't think of anything more helpful.  Be specific and you can get higher quality answers.

EDIT: rereading your question it sounds like you're finding a path on a map.  I suggest looking into A*, it may be faster if there are many paths of similar length.  If the correct path is much longer than dead ends, then DFS is likely still faster.

EDIT 2, electric boogaloo: If you are doing this check many times on a single map, and only need to know if any path exists at all, then the fastest solution is probably to do a flood fill on your map and label regions.  Then all you need to do is check if both your points are in the same region.